# MS Paint for Gnome

Tags: gnome, processing, image-editing, microsoft-paint

I want an MS Paint like program for GNOME.

GIMP is too much for me. I find it very frustrating for the simple tasks I do (adding text, arrows and circles to screenshots to highlight different features of a program).

Answer (score 16):

Something like [gnome-paint](http://code.google.com/p/gnome-paint/) ?

[image]

Comment: +1: way better than my answer :)

Comment: looks good. look the followup question: http://superuser.com/questions/37880/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

[XPaint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sf-xpaint/) should do all those things. It's not pretty, but it should get the job done.