# How do I install a .deb file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, debian, installer

How do I install a .deb file in Ubuntu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Double click will show the debian package manager and click on install button will install it

Comment: Don't assume gnome, it is unlikely but he could be using another window manager.

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

or

```
sudo gdebi-gtk package.deb
```

Which will open up a graphical installer.

Answer (score 3):

> dpkg -i [name of file].deb

You might need to add a *sudo* command in the front to elevate the command to superuser level.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu, simply double clicking the file should be enough, if not right click the item and open it with the installer.

Or.

You could use the command line way, like stated above.